Expo - Issue with background location tracking when stop, not completely terminating app. (APK)
I’ve run into an issue with my Expo app, specifically around background location tracking and app termination, and I’m hoping to get some insights from the community.
The Problem:
I’ve implemented background location tracking, which works fine in both foreground and background modes. However, when I close the app, I want to stop the location tracking completely. I have a snippet of code that successfully stops the tracking, but there’s a catch:
After stopping the location tracking, the app doesn’t fully terminate. When I reopen the app, it doesn’t reload states, assets, or other resources properly. It’s like the app is still suspended in the background.
To reset everything properly, I have to manually force close the app (e.g., swiping it away from the app switcher), which isn’t ideal.
Here’s the code snippet I’m using:


import { View, Text, Alert, Linking } from "react-native";

import React, { useEffect } from "react";



import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";

import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

import * as Location from "expo-location";

import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";

const FB = getDatabase();

const BACKGROUND_LOCATION_TASK = "background-location-task";

TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_LOCATION_TASK, async ({ data, error }) => {

  const auth = getAuth();

  if (error) {

    console.error(error);

    return;

  }

  if (data) {

    const { locations } = data as any;

    const timestamp = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {

      month: "short",

      day: "numeric",

      year: "numeric",

      hour: "numeric",

      minute: "numeric",

      second: "numeric",

      hour12: true,

    });

    console.log(`[${timestamp}] Locations captured in the background`);

    try {

      await auth.authStateReady().then(() => {

        const u = auth.currentUser;

        if (u) {

          const userLocation = ref(FB, `users/${u.uid}/location`);

          set(userLocation, {

            latitude: locations[0].coords.latitude,

            longitude: locations[0].coords.longitude,

            timestamp: Date.now(),

          });

        } else {

          console.log("No user signed in");

        }

      });

    } catch (error) {

      console.error("Firebase error:", error);

    }

  }

});

const RootLayout = () => {

  const showPermissionAlert = (message: string) => {

    Alert.alert("Permission Required", message, [

      {

        text: "Cancel",

        style: "cancel",

      },

      {

        text: "OK",

        onPress: () => {

          Linking.openSettings();

        },

      },

    ]);

  };

  const checkAndRestartLocationUpdates = async () => {

    const { status: foregroundStatus } =

      await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();

    if (foregroundStatus === "granted") {

      const { status: backgroundStatus, canAskAgain } =

        await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();

      if (backgroundStatus === "granted") {

        await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_LOCATION_TASK, {

          accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,

          timeInterval: 10000,

          distanceInterval: 0,

          foregroundService: {

            notificationTitle: "Guardcon is tracking your location",

            notificationBody: "Background location tracking is running",

            killServiceOnDestroy: true,

          },

        });

      } else {

        if (!canAskAgain) {

          showPermissionAlert(

            "Please allow background location permissions to use the app"

          );

        } else {

          await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();

        }

      }

    } else {

      showPermissionAlert("Please allow location permissions to use the app");

    }

  };

  const unregisterLocationTask = async () => {

    try {

      const isRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(BACKGROUND_LOCATION_TASK);

      if (isRegistered) {

        await Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync(BACKGROUND_LOCATION_TASK);

        await TaskManager.unregisterTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_LOCATION_TASK);

        await TaskManager.unregisterAllTasksAsync();

        console.log('Location Task Unregistered');

      }

    } catch (error) {

      console.error('Error unregistering location task:', error);

    }

  };

  

  useEffect(() => {

    checkAndRestartLocationUpdates();

    return () => {

      unregisterLocationTask();

      

    };

  }, []);

  return (

    <View>

      <Text>RootLayout</Text>

    </View>

  );

};



export default RootLayout;

This works to stop the location tracking, but it seems the app remains partially alive and doesn’t reload completely when reopened. This happens in build apk.

I had a similar issue, when I saw your code I thought it was your startLocation config but I tested and works fine.
In my case, the problem was at navigation stack level. I had two stacks defined by user and attributes. But, even when I try await to finish all the clean up some states remain unclean. This didn't happen before location task. Somehow, having the task in background is related to the app lifecycle.
My fix was remove those stacks by user and attributes, replace them for just one and redirected manually (so, the first load it doesn't depend on those auth states).
Hope this helps you to find a quick fix.
